# How can I prevent a page from not showing an client side error message when a server side include does not load?

Tags: asp.net, server-side-includes

In my ASP app, if there is an error with an include file, the entire page will not load and displays this
[image: Loading Error]

These includes are sections of the page. If it does not load, I would just want that part of the page not to load but have the rest of the content load. For example, there is a menu that helps to narrow down a list of dealers, it is a lot of code that I want to replace anyways, so I linked it as an html include.

```
<!--#include file="/dental-equipment/dealer-selection.html" -->
```

The reasoning was that:

- I could work on a different better block of code outside of the project without having to open to main page.
- I would not have to document so much in version control. Because I could work on this outside of the project.
- I figured this way I could segregate bugs.
- It kept each page cleaner to and more organized.

And even if this include did not load, a user could still view and find dealers.

So while I am at it feel free to point out any noob mistakes I am making with project planning here.

Comment: did you tried to put load this "include file" like loading ascx file between try and catch and render error message in the final html if you want to know that this include have error ?

Comment: You have to show us the code where you try to load the 'section'.  It can be wrapped in a try-catch like Cairo mentions, but it'd be better to fix the root.

Comment: You should not use server-side includes in ASP.NET applications. Learn to use user controls instead.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thank you, I did a search on Google after you mentioned that and found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyt68f1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but was wondering if you may have suggestions for anything good sources, etc. Otherwise I will keep searching on Google and YouTube.

Comment: See [ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx).